# Not able to go to the graphical mode in RHEL 6

Tags: linux, xorg

I was using win-7. I tried to install RHEL 6 today. [dual boot]

> / = 40000 MB and /boot = 1000 MB

The installation completed successfully.

The problem is that it is not showing the graphical mode. Only the terminal mode is available. I tried

> chvt 1-7

but I am unable to go to the graphical mode. It is not appearing. What should I do?

**System config:**

MSI CR420 Laptop.
Intel core i3-350M

**Edited** after following [user76871's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/302332/not-able-to-go-to-the-graphical-mode-in-rhel-6/302333#302333):

There is no `Xorg.0.log` file in `/var/log/`, There is no `xdm` in `/etc/init.d/`, there is no `kdm` also.

I tried `startx` that also didn't work. I tried `system-config-display` but the display is not available at system-config-

Comment: Reason for close vote?

Comment: This question is on the wrong forum, it should probably be on SU instead. And, if you wat someone to help you, you need to add more information to your question. As it is now, there is not enough info to be able to help you.

Comment: probably it is not a programming related question (i did not vote)

Comment: OK and the reason for down-vote? Same? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Actually at the installation time it asks whether you want to install a `basic server` or want to include `desktop` and some other features. By default the `BASIC SERVER` option is marked and hence it doesn't include the graphical interface. I reinstalled with the `Desktop` option and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Look in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and hit / and type `\(EE` then hit Enter, then to find more errors hit /-Enter.

Do `/etc/init.d/xdm OR kdm restart` to try to launch X once you fix the error; you may have to google for them.

(sidenote: Sometimes this may indicate that you're missing appropriate graphics drivers, which sometimes happens when they get out of sync with the kernel while upgrading and using proprietary drivers... but this would be uncommon when installing.)

login as root and
try init 5 (command for graphical run level)
or in 
vi /etc/inittab
check default run level is 5 or not